# horizontal alignment label img div

Tags: html, alignment, label

Inside a long cell I have a image aligned to the left. Fine. Now I would like to insert a label right of the image that is aligned to the very right. When I try this the label appears always directly next to the image, hence isn't shifted to the very right, to the cell's end.

I tried variants of:

```
<img align="left" src="..." /><span align="right"><label>Mytext</label></span>
```

But the text is never shifted to the very right, it always stays directly next to the image.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
Fixed with:

```
<img align="left" src="..." /><span style="float:right"><label>Mytext</label></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<span alignment="right">
```

to

```
<span style="float:right">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SEXQ6/)**

There is no "alignment" attribute so use just plain old CSS.